# dynamically retrieving data from ui:inputs, using component.find.get

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript-controller

I dynamically render ui:inputTextArea's depending on active user. Making it possible for them to update where they wish. I was hoping I could dynamically retrieve the data as well when they hit save but I beleive I am missing something.
Code follows:

.cmp

```
<ui:inputTextArea aura:id="editable"
value="{!comment.Comment__c}" cols="55" rows="2" placeholder="!comment.Comment__c}"/>
```

.js

```
var getEditableFields = component.find("editable");//Returns Input fields with id = editable
var newData = [];
for (var i in getEditableFields)//retrieves data from editable fields.
{
    newData[i] = getEditableFields[i].get("v.value");
}
```

error.

```
[getEditableFields[i].get is not a function]
```

Comment: `var getEditableFields = component.find("editable");`Is it returning array of Returns Input fields.It is not returning as array so only it showing `[getEditableFields[i].get is not a function]`

Comment: @vignesh ok I got my error. the moment there are more than one editable fields it builds succesfully (cause its an array). if there is only one editable field it holds single value and cannot run through array with [i].... overlooked such a simple thing. Thank you very much, this has been bothering me for sometime :) but problem is now solved.

Comment: Ok @Mrd if there is only one editable field it will return a object you may skip that  iteration ,you can directly get the value `getEditableFields.get("v.value");`